# React componentWillUnmount - why cancelling anything if component will be removed from DOM anyways and thus stop timers etc?

Tags: reactjs

I wonder and couldnt find anything about the following: if a component will unmount, then all subscriptions or timers etc will stop. Why do I need to remove them inside componentWillUnmount if that would happen without using componentWillUnmount anyways?!
For example if I have setInterval in my componentDidMount, it will stop once the component unmounts so why would I cancel the setInterval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setInterval` and `setTimeout` are attached to `window`, not to your component, so it does not get cleared when your component unmount and it might still call your callback function referencing your component, e.g. calling `this.setState` which will raise a warning if the component is unmounted.

Comment: Thank you. A side question: if its not attached to my component, why isnt setting state inside a setInterval, throwing me an errow: [..] of undefined, since if my component is unmounted, it doesnt have state anymore and in setInterval i would try to set it? Instead I only see a warning

Comment: Well I believe that is because your component is a js function or class that is imported and still exists — technically speaking — even after being unmounted. So it is define. It's just the way react works.

Answer (score 1):

No, it won't be cancelled. that's why you've to cancelled all the subscriptions in componentWillUnmount. you can check it by yourself, bind any event listner to window from inside a component write a console in it, even when your component will be removed from the dom you can still see the console and event triggering if you didn't removed it on unmounting.

Yes you may not see the effect in the dom after your component has been unmounted, but still it might be running in the background which can lead to bugs or it can effect the performance of your app.

Comment: thank you, I believed it wont get cancelled and was confused.